# Screwturn Wiki V3.0.5.600 Sub-Categories

Tags: screwturn

I am in the midst of setting up an internal wiki (Screwturn V3.0.5.600) for my department. I'm at the point of setting up the basic structure and I believe I will need both categories and sub-categories.

I've gone through the documentation and I have not found instructions on setting up sub-categories.  Is it possible?  Is there perhaps a plugin that makes it possible?

I gave setting up my major categories as namespaces and then my subcategories as categories in each namespace, but that just didn't feel right.

Thank you, in advance, for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's currently any real way to harness subcategory functionality in STW.  If you explained more what your structure is and why you need it set up that way, perhaps people could offer suggestions.

Offhand, you could try to set up semantic sub-categories by giving different categories related names.  I.e., 'Development', 'Development-project1', 'Development-project2'.

Aside from that, what about using the keywords functionality?